# npm ERR! code ENOSELF and Refusing to install package with name "mermaid" under a package

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "mermaid" under a package
npm ERR! also called "mermaid". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remember the code `npm install mermaid`
2. Type `sudo nano package.json`
3. Change the name of package from "mermaid" to "mermaid1" and save
   with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
4. Try to install with the step 1 code.